# Cannot scrape certain DIV tags using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the articles (their titles/links) on a certain topic (for instance Machine learning) from this website. https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=machine%20learning&sort=relevance

The div tag that I need to access is  which is nested under several other div tags.

This is what I have tried so far. I getting empty lists. Any help is appreciated.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

# Get all the paper url in the search result
def paper_crawler():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox('path')
    driver.get ('https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=machine%20learning&sort=relevance&fos=chemistry')
    result_counts = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="result-count"]')
    print(result_counts)
    for item in result_counts:
        count = item.text
        print(count)
    #search_result_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//div[contains(@class,"result-page")]/article/header/div/a')
    search_result_urls = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="result-page"]/article/header/div/a')
    print(search_result_urls)
    for item in search_result_urls:
        paper_url =  item.get_attribute('href')
        print(paper_url)
    search_result_titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="result-page"]/article/header/div/a/span')
    for item in search_result_titles:
        paper_title = item.text
        print(paper_title)
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    paper_crawler ()
```

Comment: The post title says you're looking for `div` tags, but the code is looking for `a` and `span` tags.  Which is it?

Comment: use `API` and make your life easier !!! https://www.semanticscholar.org/api/1/search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `API` better and make your life easier. parse whatever you want.

```
import requests


data = {
    "queryString": "machine learning",
    "page": 1,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "sort": "relevance",
    "authors": [],
    "coAuthors": [],
    "venues": [],
    "yearFilter": None,
    "requireViewablePdf": False,
    "publicationTypes": [],
    "externalContentTypes": []
}
r = requests.post(
    'https://www.semanticscholar.org/api/1/search', json=data).json()

print(r)
```

Comment: Works flawless. But OP only provided the link as `https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=machine%20learning&sort=relevance&fos=chemistry`, where did you find `https://www.semanticscholar.org/api/1/search` ?

Comment: @DebanjanB that question should not came from 66k rep user :P https://i.ibb.co/sJpZn3d/Capture.png

Comment: @DebanjanB I’m not the OP of this answer, but I image it’s by inspecting the network activity when searching on the site.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Not sure if high rep users are allowed or not to ask questions but any question raised with Selenium tag, I tend to ask a lot of counter questions while constructing answers whilst I'm yet to touch _Requests_. Thanks for the snapshot though ;)

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderCécile you are right, but somehow I am unable to find the _Method_ tab :( getting hold of the POST method seems impossible :)

Comment: @DebanjanB What do you mean, the _method_ tab?

Comment: @DebanjanB it's ok. am just kidding ! take it easy

Comment: @AlexanderCécile See the [snapshot](https://i.ibb.co/sJpZn3d/Capture.png) provided within comments. The POST request can be observed within `Network tab`, 3 columns are there, _Method_, _Domain_ and _File_. The POST request is in Method column. Am I correct?

Comment: @DebanjanB yes that's it

Comment: @DebanjanB It looks like it, although I’m a Safari user ;)

Comment: @DebanjanB choose Safari > Preferences, click Advanced, then select “Show Develop menu in menu bar.”  then network tab

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη All this while I was tinkering with Chrome :(

Comment: @DebanjanB both safari and chrome have all options :P

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Oh yes they do, no issues there, I just wasn’t confident in my ability to remember the Firefox UI lol

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I am very new to this and still learning the process of scrapping. I am not very familiar with APIs, but I think working with one is going to make this a lot easier. Did the website provide that json format you have in data variable? I couldn't find the source of it. Thank you for your suggestions and help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @utsav do you ask about how i got the `API` `url` ?

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη yes the API url and the response format (json data)

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη Now that I have the response in r variable from your code snippet above. How do I parse the dictionary using Beautiful soup? or any other way for the matter?

Comment: @utsav r is a `dict` so you can access it's keys ! `print(r.keys())`, also if my answer helps you so you can select the √  mark beside the answer.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I was able to get the info I wanted traversing through the dictionary using keys (thank you!) now how do I do this for all remaining about 1000 pages. I noticed our json data has a "page" key with '1' value. Is there a way I could loop through all the remaining pages and scrape all the information like I did for the first page. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The page is loaded but not completely rendered when you start to search for the elements.
A "time.sleep(5)" after

> driver.get ('https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=machine%20learning&sort=relevance&fos=chemistry')
>   should help as a quick workaround.

For a better, more robust solution you should wait for result_counts to be greater than 0 for a few seconds or the page being the error page (https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=learning333&sort=relevance&fos=chemistry).

Answer (score 0):

To extract the *Title* and *HREF* attributes of the articles you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('https://www.semanticscholar.org/search?q=machine%20learning&sort=relevance&fos=chemistry')
  my_titles = [my_elem.text for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-selenium-selector='title-link']>span")))]
  my_hrefs = [my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-selenium-selector='title-link']")))]
  for i,j in zip(my_titles, my_hrefs):
      print("{} link is {}".format(i, j))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  UCI Repository of Machine Learning Databases link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/UCI-Repository-of-Machine-Learning-Databases-Blake/e068be31ded63600aea068eacd12931efd2a1029
  Energy landscapes for machine learning. link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Energy-landscapes-for-machine-learning.-Ballard-Das/735d4099d3be0d919ddedb054043e6763205e0f7
  Finding Nature′s Missing Ternary Oxide Compounds Using Machine Learning and Density Functional Theory. link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Finding-Nature%E2%80%B2s-Missing-Ternary-Oxide-Compounds-Hautier-Fischer/e3ab9e1162fc8f63d215dfdb21801ef5e1fde7b5
  Distributed secure quantum machine learning link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Distributed-secure-quantum-machine-learning-Sheng-Zhou/ef944614bfc82b1dedfea19ff249a97ceea5ad90
  Neural-Symbolic Machine Learning for Retrosynthesis and Reaction Prediction. link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Neural-Symbolic-Machine-Learning-for-Retrosynthesis-Segler-Waller/71cc9eefb17d7c4d1062162523b5fdad7ca66a2a
  Transferable Machine-Learning Model of the Electron Density link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Transferable-Machine-Learning-Model-of-the-Electron-Grisafi-Fabrizio/f809258b65a00a06f9584e76620e6c6395cf81eb
  Crystal structure representations for machine learning models of formation energies link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Crystal-structure-representations-for-machine-of-Faber-Lindmaa/1bdca98dc8c730ee92d5b19d2973a5bf461a500a
  Machine learning for quantum mechanics in a nutshell link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Machine-learning-for-quantum-mechanics-in-a-Rupp/29b9ff8f4a26acc90e6182e1e749f15f688bc7cf
  Machine-Learning-Augmented Chemisorption Model for CO2 Electroreduction Catalyst Screening. link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Machine-Learning-Augmented-Chemisorption-Model-for-Ma-Li/d6f30032c8fac43a8eabf2b67d2e84db6d3d0409
  Adaptive machine learning framework to accelerate ab initio molecular dynamics link is https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Adaptive-machine-learning-framework-to-accelerate-Botu-Ramprasad/c9934d684fcc0b8ac6ed25b34d96e726cf2d7b99
  ```